# Wordpress Multisite installed on a subdomain not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I have installed a Wordpress Multisite setup on a subdomain of my main website (let's call it subdomain.website.co.uk).

I want to run the Multisite installation as a subdirectory setup, so users can multiple subdirectories (e.g. subdomain.website.co.uk/directory1, subdomain.website.co.uk/directory2, etc.).

However, when I navigate to subdomain.website.co.uk/directory1 all I get is a blank white page. Is this because I've installed the Mutisite in a subdomain?

Comment: Have you check your error log files ?

Comment: @Florian Lemaitre the log files say the site is responding fine